# Use python script to edit data in logstash

Tags: python, elasticsearch, logstash, mysql-connector

I have a `logstash` configuration that gets data from a MySQL database and sends the data to `elasticsearch`.
This is my configuration:

```
input {
  jdbc {
    clean_run => true
    jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://IP:PORT/DATABASE"
    jdbc_user => "myuser"
    jdbc_password => "mypassword"
    use_column_value => true
    tracking_column => "field1"
    schedule => "*/2 * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT * FROM test"
  }
}

**need something here before the 'output' section ?**

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://ELASTICSEARCH_IP:PORT"]
    index => "myindexname"
    document_id => "%{field1}"
  }
}
```

Everything's working fine, but I need to add some columns that have values dependent upon other column values, so I tried writing a Python script to do this. Is there a way to execute a python script to add/edit columns before data are sent in `elasticsearch`? Do I need the `filter` option?

EDIT :
For exemple, I use my python script to :

- create a week number column based on a datetime field.
- create a month number column based on a datetime field.
- edit the 'name' column and replace some special characters ('/', '-', ':', etc...)
- create linear trendline based on an another column.
- create an moving average line based on an another column.
- replace some columns values (ex : replace 'y' by 'yes' and 'n' by 'no').

Comment: I don't think you can execute python script in Logstash pipeline config, but you can write your own filter plugin in `ruby` programming. Here is the approach  
 https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-ruby.html

Comment: You can execute a `ruby` code inside the `fitler` block, but depending on what you want to do you can use one of the many native filters that logstash has. For example, if you want to add a new field based on the value of other fields, you can do that using the `mutate` filter. Update your question with an example of what you want to do.

Comment: I just edited my question to put some examples of what my python script do.
Thank you for your help :) If there is no possibiliy to use python, I'll turn to Ruby code but I'm not comfortable with this language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did the thing with the ruby ​​code.
Thanks mates for your help!